# Laravel 4 - artisan

Tags: command, laravel, remote-server

I have problem with artisan commands. I get only three commands, when I execute "php artisan list". Where are other commands? When I copy my project on my local server everything works great. It is only on remote server and I don't have any idea how to solve it. Have you any ideas?

Comment: Did you `$ composer install` on your remote server?

Comment: Yes. I got below message:
`Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "optimize" is not defined.
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:

    [InvalidArgumentException]
    Command "optimize" is not defined.
`
Maybe above warning is the cause of this?

Comment: Ok. It works :) The SAPI was the reason. I run the artisan file with `php-cli` and all commands from artisan are available :)